# Puppet: cron schedule - "is not a valid hour" error

Tags: syntax, cron, puppet

I need to schedule a cron job for daily running every 30 mins from 0 to 6 and from 13 to 23. I tried this code:

```
cron { "MyJob":
    ensure  => present,
    command => "my-cron-command",
    user    => 'root',
    hour    => "0-6,13-23",
    minute  => '*/30',
    environment => "MY_ENV"
}
```

This fails with

```
0-6,13-23 is not a valid hour
```

What `hour` format should I use? Do I need any other changes in cron clause?

Comment: Ha, I was *just* about to say [this was reported as a bug](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3484), but I realize you just filed it. I did [notice this, however](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4172), on their old bug system.

Comment: My first thought was that that syntax might not be supported by all `cron` implementations (Vixie cron does support it), but it's valid for any POSIX-conforming implementation and supported on Solaris 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are putting more than one values for any attributes. Put them in an array list. SO, the hour will be ['0-6','13-23']

Comment: how is this different from the accepted answer? For writing good answers please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 4):

Close, but no cigar.

```
cron { "MyJob":
    ensure  => present,
    command => "my-cron-command",
    user    => 'root',
    hour    => [ "0-6", "13-23" ],
    minute  => '*/30',
    environment => "MY_ENV"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should just list the hours:

```
cron { "MyJob":
    ensure  => present,
    command => "my-cron-command",
    user    => 'root',
    hour    => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],
    minute  => '*/30',
    environment => "MY_ENV"
}
```

Works, but `hour    => "0-6,13-23"` does not.